# Modalverbähnliche verben mit Infinitiv mit zu

Tags: verb, infinitive

I can't understand "Modalverbähnliche verben mit zu" because the meaning of verb changes when we use "zu+Infinitiv" for example: verb ( Vermögen ≠ Vermögen zu+Infinitiv) ( es heißt ≠ es heißt +zu+inf ). Can you please help me with these verbs.

Comment: Note that "(das) Vermögen" and "vermögen" are different words; i do not really understand the problem, can you provide more information about what you don't understand?

Comment: The term *modalverbähnliche Verben* is unfortunately used in various meanings, so you should include a source. Also, some spelled out examples would be nice. As it is, I don't understand which problems with regard to *vermögen, heißen* you are referring to.

Comment: Ok, first thanks for your help, I know there's a difference between ( das Vermögen und vermögen, das ein Verb ist) the problem is ( das Verb "vermögen" wird mit zu+inf benutzt. Zum Beispiel : er vermag die Lektion zu verstehen) I found this sentence in my book so that made me a little bit confused, but it's ok now. I meant with "modalverbähnliche verben" the verbs that come with "zu+inf" and there meaning change. (Sein ≠ sein zu+inf : 1/ sie ist krank ≠ die Ausländer sind gut zu behandeln)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a tricky issue. Some verbs take noun objects, some combine with the other verbs in the infinitive, and some take an additional clause. There are many that do more than one of these depending on the meaning. The additional clause may be introduced with either *zu* or *dass* depending on circumstances. Verbs often have multiple meanings, and these meanings require different sentence structures. Sometimes it's not possible to tell which meaning is being used without analyzing the structure of the sentence. This kind of thing happens in English as well, and (I would assume) in most languages. For example in "I want ice cream" and "I want you to clean you room," the verb "want" has different meanings, one says you want some thing and other says you want some action to be performed.

With a *zu* clause, the verb is talking about something happening. This something is described in the *zu* clause, which is just like a typical subclause except there is no subject and it's introduced with *zu* instead of a conjunction. (One might say that the *zu* is the conjunction but that's not important.) Another difference is that a typical subclause uses a finite verb, but a *zu* clause, having no subject, uses the infinitive. For example:

- *Er hat die Eier vergessen. -- "He forgot eggs."
- *Er hat vergessen, im Laden Eier zu kaufen.* -- "He forgot to buy eggs at the store."

In the first case *vergessen* is used as a transitive verb with *die Eier* the noun object. The second case uses a different meaning of *vergessen* which takes a phrase instead of a noun. You can state the meaning of the phrase as a sentence on its own:

- *Er hat im Laden Eier gekauft.* -- "He bought eggs at the store."

But we're trying to say what he forgot to do, not what he would have done, so we need *vergessen* in combination with the previous sentence. To do this in German you remove the subject since it's already in the *Er hat vergessen...* part, change the verb to the infinitive, and put in *zu* to connect it up with the first part of the sentence.

There are a number a variations on this general idea. For example sometimes the *zu* clause is combined with an adverb as well.

- *Es war einfach für ihn, Eier im Laden zu kaufen.* -- "It was easy for him to buy eggs at the store."

A *zu* clause can also be combined with certain additional words such as *ob*, *ohne* and *statt*. You can form similar clauses with *dass*, but these are more like a typical subclause since they have a subject and a finite verb:

- *Sie hat vergessen, dass er im Laden Eier gekauft hat.* - "She forgot that he bought eggs at the store."

There is a similar construction using what is called the gerund in English. This is the same as the present participle in English, formed by adding "-ing" to the verb. German doesn't use its present participle for anything except to form an adjective, and instead it uses the infinitive. So:

- *Sie sah ihn im Laden Eier kaufen.* -- "She saw him buying eggs at the store." (You could also go with *Sie hat ihn im Laden Eier kaufen sehen,* but this is more awkward.)

This "gerund infinitive" is only used with certain verbs, and fortunately these mostly correspond to verbs in English where the "-ing" form would be used. This includes sense verbs such as *sehen*, *hören*, *fühlen*, as well as a number of others. There are also the six "modal" verbs which combine directly with another verb with no subclause. These are *dürfen*, *können*, *mögen*, *müssen*, *sollen* and *wollen*. Of these, *mögen* and *wollen* also have meanings as ordinary transitive verbs.

I couldn't find any examples of *heißen* being used with a *zu* clause. Wiktionary does list such a meaning but it's labeled "archaic".

(Full disclosure: I'm a learner myself and I feel I'm right at the edge of my comfort zone with this answer. Hopefully I've gotten most of it right.)

Comment: "heißen" is a bit tricky - there's one archaic meaning of it that boils down to "to order someone do something" - *Die Königin hieß ihren Jäger, Dornröschen zu finden und zu töten*.

Comment: @tofro: Good example. But wait, I thought that was *Schneewittchen*. Maybe I saw a version where they combined the stories. English has "call on" which has about the same meaning: "The queen called on the hunter to find and slay Sleeping Beauty."

Comment: No claim on historic authenticity ;) Just an example

Comment: "With a zu clause, the verb is talking about something happening." Does this actually mean anything? The verb is always talking about something happening...

Comment: I think this answer should be rewritten. There seems to be something deep here, and probably you could epxlain it between with the knowledge you've gained over approx 2 years